# How does multilevel grouping work?

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express

I am not sure how the query below is processed. I read this query and i know what output it will give me. But, i wanted to know how it is processed conceptually.

```
select FirstName, LastName, COUNT(CertificateId) as CertificatesAcheived
from Employee left join [Achivements]
on Employee.EmpID = [Achivements].EmpID
group by FirstName, LastName
```

Ok, this is how i think it works (tell me if i am wrong) -

First, pairs of the type (First Name, LastName) are generated, ie (f1,n1)(f1,n2)(f2,n5)(f3,n5)
etc. Many people can have the same first name and/or last name.

Then, for each such pair, Count(---) will count the number of Certificates achieved.

(...and yes, i know that employees with the exact same name will be considered as one employee, but that is not important for me)

Comment: What is the actual question? What do you want to achieve, and what makes you think this query doesn't?

Comment: @skyscraper your explanation of how you think it works seem correct.

Comment: @Arkain - do you know any book which explains it like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about sql express 2008 but this is how it generally works:

First a join is created

```
from Employee left join [Achivements] on Employee.EmpID = [Achivements].EmpID
```

then groups are created:

```
group by FirstName, LastName
```

all rows with same firstname and lastname will fall in same group

the output will be one row for each group: firstname, lastname, and count of rows in the group

```
select FirstName, LastName, COUNT(CertificateId) as CertificatesAcheived
```